# Mysql PHP Обновление значения в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Вот собственно хочу поменять, но по условию изменения не происходят.

Весь код:

```
       <div class="add">
        <center>
            <span><strong>Карточки</strong></span>
            <a href="/admin/components/carts/add_carts.php" class="back-element">добавить карточку</a>

            <div class="form-add">
                <form method="post">
                    <select name="item">
                        <option value="series">Серия</option>
                        <option value="num">Номер</option>
                        <option value="status">Статус</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" name="find" value="" placeholder="Текст поиска..." class="calc_input">
                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Поиск / Все элементы" class="calc_submit">
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>


            <?
            if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
                $search = trim($_POST["find"]);
                $item = trim($_POST["item"]);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE $item LIKE '%$search%' ORDER by id DESC";
//                print_r($query);
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                echo "<div class='CSSTableGenerator'><table><tr><td>Серия</td><td>Номер</td><td>Открыто</td><td>Закрыто</td><td>Окончание</td><td>Статус</td></tr>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<tr>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["series"], '</a></td>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["num"], '</a></td>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["date_start"], '</a></td>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["date_finish"], '</a></td>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["activity"], '</a></td>
<td><a href="?id=', $row["id"], '">', $row["status"], '</a></td>
</tr>';
                }
                echo "</table></div><br>";
                require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/main/footer.php");
                exit();
            }


            // А это форма редактирования записи
            if (!empty($_GET["id"])) {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE id=" . $_GET['id'] . "";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            }

            // Добавление
            if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO carts (series,num,date_start,date_finish,date_last_use,status,history,summ) VALUES ('{$_POST['series']}', '{$_POST['num']}', '{$_POST['date_start']}','{$_POST['date_finish']}','{$_POST['date_last_use']}','{$_POST['status']}','{$_POST['history']}')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            //Корректировка
            if (isset($_POST["edit"])) {
                $query = "UPDATE carts SET series='{$_POST['series']}',num='{$_POST['num']}',date_start='{$_POST['date_start']}',date_finish='{$_POST['date_finish']}',summ='{$_POST['summ']}',status='{$_POST['status']}',history='{$_POST['history']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                unset($row);
            }
            //Удаление
            if (isset($_POST["delete"])) {
                $query = "DELETE FROM carts WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                mysql_query($query);
                unset($row);
            }

            if (!empty($_GET["id"])) {
                echo '
<div class="form-add">
<form method="post"><table border="0">
<tr>
    <td><input style="-moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none" type="text" size=10 value="' . $row["status"] . '" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><select size=2 name="status">
    <option disabled>Статус карты</option>
    <option value="Активно">Активно</option>
    <option value="Деактивированно">Деактивированно</option>
    <option value="Просрочено">Просрочено</option>
   </select></td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input style="-moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none" type="text" size=16 value="' . $row["activity"] . '" readonly>Истечет срок</td>
</tr>
   <tr><td><select size=2 name="activity">
                    <option disabled>Активировать карты</option>
                    <option value="' . date((time($row["date_start"]) + 3600 * 24 * 30)) . '">На 1 месяц</option>
                    <option value="' . date((time($row["date_start"]) + 3600 * 24 * 60)) . '">На 6 месяцев</option>
                    <option value="' . date((time($row["date_start"]) + 3600 * 24 * 365)) . '">На 365 день</option>
   </select></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"  size=32 name="series" placeholder="Серия" value="' . $row["series"] . '"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" size=32 name="num" placeholder="Номер карты" value="' . $row["num"] . '"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Открыта<input type="text" size=32 name="date_start" value="' . $row["date_start"] . '"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Закрыта<input type="text" size=32 name="date_finish" value="' . $row["date_finish"] . '"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Последнеее изменение<input style="-moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none" type="text" size=19 name="date_last_use" value="' . $row["date_last_use"] . '" readonly></td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea name="history" placeholder="История" cols=80 rows=2>' . $row["history"] . '</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input style="float:right" name="summ" size="19" value="'.$row["summ"].'"></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET["id"] . '">
<tr><td></td><td>
';
                echo '<input id="button" style="left: 170px;" type="submit" name="edit" value="Сохранить">';
                echo '<input id="button" type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить">';
            }
            echo "</tr></table></form><br>";?>
            <?
            $true_activity = strtotime($row["activity"]);
            $true_start = strtotime($row["date_start"]);
                if ($true_activity == $true_start) {
                    $row["status"]="Просрочено";
                    $query = "UPDATE carts SET status='{$_POST['status']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    unset($row);
                }
            ?>
        </center>

    </div>
```

Собственно код обработки обновления:

```
    <?
    $true_activity = strtotime($row["activity"]);
    $true_start = strtotime($row["date_start"]);
        if ($true_activity == $true_start) {
            $row["status"]="Просрочено";
            $query = "UPDATE carts SET status='{$_POST['status']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            unset($row);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: а управление этой строке попадает? что веб-сервер пишет в error_log? дополните, пожалуйста, этой информацией ваш вопрос, нажав [edit].

Comment: Если остальной код выполняется, то вангую что данное выражение  `$true_activity == $true_start` возвращает `false`, поэтому обновление не происходит. А вообще код ужасен, в первую очередь тем, что содержит дырень в безопасности. Надеюсь вас это печалит

Comment: @ArchDemon Он возвращает true, дело в том, что в БД не вносится это значение. Все столбцы обнуляются, а должно просто столбец status смениться с "Активно", на "Просрочено". Вот и всё. Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Он возвращает true, дело в том, что в БД не вносится это значение. Все столбцы обнуляются, а должно просто столбец status смениться с "Активно", на "Просрочено". Вот и всё. Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: что именно находится в переменных, упомянутых в запросе (`$_POST['status']` и `$_POST['id']`), перед его выполнением, вы уже проверили?

Comment: попробуйте выполнить этот же запрос с этими же значениями переменных с помощью удобного вам средства — программы `mysql`, или *phpmyadmin*, или ещё чего-нибудь.